# NodeJS, getting username of logged in user within route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, body-parser

I am getting in to NodeJS and have followed some video tutorials for making stuff, to understand NodeJS and Express. It turned more in to copying as little were explained, so tried to make my own thing using what I learned and so on.

Making a simple login function with PassportJS, ExpressJs and Mongoose.
The login and stuff works, and I can get the username of the currently logged in user and display it if I define it within the main app.js using this:

```
app.get("/stuff", (req,res) => {
    res.render("stuff.html", {username:req.user.username});
});
```

Now if I want to make nice and structured by using router, I cannot get it to work. It throws error saying `username` is undefined, making page unable to render. The router itself works if I don't pass any variable or use variables I know will work (e.g. `var x = "Hello"; res.render … {msg:x});`).

Part of the `app.js` that handle routes:

```
var stuff = require("./routes/stuff");
app.use("/stuff", stuff);

module.exports.app;
```

I've tried to `cont x = require("…")` basically everything that is in the `app.js` in this `stuff.js` file, but to no avail, so removed everything but express + routes to get fresh start.

How do I pass the username that is working in `app.js` in to the routed file? Preferably make it automatically do to every page if possible, using `app.get("*")…` or something.

Entire `stuff.js`:

```
/* Routes */
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

/* Stuff */
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("stuff.html", {username:req.user.username});
    console.log(req.user.username);
    next();
});

/* Bottom */
module.exports = router;
```

Login section of `app.js`:

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', 
        {
            successRedirect: '/dashboard',
            failureRedirect: '/login',
            failureFlash: 'Wrong login'
        }
), function(req,res) {
        console.log("Hello " + req.user.username);
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done) {
    User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err,user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username,password,callback) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err,user) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user) {
            return callback(null, false, {msg: "shit"});
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err,isMatch) {
            if(err) return callback(err);
            if(isMatch) {
                return callback(null, user);
            } else {
                return callback(null, false, {msg:"Something"});
            }
        });
    });
}));
```

The `users.js` file for handling registering new users, if that's relevant:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/users");
const db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

/* Data schema */
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback) {
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(testPw, hash, callback) {
    bcrypt.compare(testPw, hash, function(err,isMatch) {
            callback(null,isMatch);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are trying to pass your username to the preferably every file including your router file. What I do for this to use middleware in app.js to pass every page. Or you can simply implement passport implementation in the other page as well which could be useless i guess.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.currentUser=req.user
  next()
}
```

Then, you can use use your currentUser in every page when you try to render.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, probably after following the same tutorials...
I found that the function you need in the app.js is:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res,next){
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
})
```

it should be in the app.js already. Now, in all of the other page you should be able to use req.user.username